# CI3 Não Carrega o model no servidor da umbler

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou fazendo um teste no serviços da umbler, mais estou tendo problema para carregar o model. estou utilizando ci3 e estou carregado os model como de costume.

```
$this->load->model('main_model');
```

Mais está dando um erro

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: RuntimeException
Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Main_model
Filename: /home/bikeradical.com.br/public/system/core/Loader.php
Line Number: 314
Backtrace:
File: /home/bikeradical.com.br/public/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Dizendo que não foi encontrado mais o meu model está no lugar certo models/main_model.php, em outro servidor carrega, apenas nesse que não carrega. Alguém pode me ajudar.

Comment: Qual o nome do seu arquivo e qual o nome da classe?

Comment: O nome do arquivo é main_model.php e o nome da class é class Main_model extends CI_Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No codeIgniter 3 a primeira letra do nome da classe deve ser maiúscula, as demais minúsculas e o nome do arquivo deve obrigatoriamente ser igual ao nome da classe, essa regra é aplicada aos controllers também.

```
Classe    |Arquivo       |
Main_model|Main_model.php|Válido 
User      |user_model.php|inválido
```

> Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of
>   the name lowercase. Make sure your class extends the base Model class.
>
> The file name must match the class name

[Documentação CI3 - Model](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model)

[Documentação CI3 - Controller](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world)

Mude o nome do arquivo de `main_model.php` para `Main_model.php`.

Comment: Vou fazer isso, pra ver mais então mudou no ci3 porque no dois utilizava dessa forma mais estranho que em outro servidor está ok e na minha máquina local também.

Comment: @ClaytonEduardoMergulhão sim mudou.

Comment: isso é só pra model para controller também?

Comment: Se aplica a controllers também. Primeira inicial maiuscula, demais minusculas e o arquivo deve ter o mesmo nome da classe. @ClaytonEduardoMergulhão

Comment: Obrigado pela dica  vou realizar os teste e se der tudo certo aviso vc, deus te abençoe.

Comment: Resolveu o problema era isso mesmo que o @rray me disse que seria, muito obrigado meu amigo.