# Couchdb e codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, couchdb

estou com um probleminha aqui, tenho um trabalho para fazer e preciso integrar o codeigniter com o couchdb, encontrei uma biblioteca no github, segui o tutorial de instalação e tudo, mais mesmo assim ela teima em não funcionar, penso ser por que ela foi desenvolvida para para uma versão mais antiga do codeigniter, e como estou usando a versão 3.0.2 não sei como faze-la funcionar, mesmo que as bibliotecas estejam incluídas o localhost me retorna o o seguint erro "Unable to load the requested class: Couchdb". Alguem já resolvel este problema?

Comment: Como está o nome do arquivo dessa classe?

Comment: o arquivo que deve carregar as biblioteca é couchdb.php

Comment: Mude o nome do arquivo  para `Couchdb.php` com o `C` maiusculo.

Comment: pocha rray muito obrigado, obrigado de verdade, resouvel o meu problema.

Comment: No CI3 mudou a regra de carregamento das classes olha aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85673/91

Comment: Muito  obrigado rray, funcionaou, obrigado de verdade, resolveu o meu problema. nota 10.